# AI algorithm for calculation

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am trying to use Artificial Intelligence algorithm to replace a system which identifies correct quantity. The quantity will be considered as "Yes" if it's in multiple of a number and "No" is it's not in multiples. Also, the other factor which it uses are > and < a number. I tried to use scikit learn RandomForestClassifier algorithms, but it doesn't get trained for the multipliers. Can you please suggest an algorithm which will best suit this. Thanks.

I tried to use scikit learn RandomForestClassifier algorithms

```
import sklearn
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn import svm
from TFANN import ANNR
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
data=pd.read_csv('qty.csv')

data.head()
data.info()
validate=LabelEncoder()
data['Type']=validate.fit_transform(data['Type'])
data['ans']=validate.fit_transform(data['ans'])



data.head()
sns.countplot(data['ans'])
X=data.drop('ans', axis=1)
y = data['ans']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
#sc=StandardScaler()
#X_train=sc.fit_transform(X_train)
#X_test=sc.fit_transform(X_test)
print(X_train)
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200)
rfc.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred_rfc=rfc.predict([[0,12,20]])
#print(X_test)
print (pred_rfc)
```

If I want to predict multiple of 12 in the following, it doesn't `enter code here`work as expected. How can I use AI algorithm to train multiples?
pred_rfc=rfc.predict([[0,12,2400]])

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd start by further defining the problem.  Do you need it to work for only multiples in your training set, all multiples within a specified range, or all multiples unconstrained?

If you only need it to work for values in your training set, then most ML algorithms will work just fine.  If you need it to work on all values in a specified range, then again most ML algorithms will work just fine, but some might require some additional refinement.  If you need it to work for all multiples, then you need to focus on selecting an appropriate underlying model.

A random forest like you are using here will not perform well beyond the extremes (high and low) of your training data because the underlying model does not extrapolate beyond the extremes of the training data.  There are plenty of alternative models that can precisely match multiples however, for example a sine wave.  The period of a sine wave determines how often the value reaches `1`, so if you learn the correct period from the data, then you can predict all multiples with some degree of success.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want ti work for all multiples. When I try to use the above code for a multiple outside the training set, the results are incorrect. Can you please elaborate a bit on sine wave. Thank you.